# replace href attribute in anchor element

Tags: javascript, regex, wordpress

I need a code for replace the `href` inside my `<div>` or in full html document (its same).

My content is look like:

```
<div class="entry-content post_content">
<center><a href="http://misite.com/go/redirect.php?q=post title" target="_blank"><img src="http://mysite.com/img/redirect.png" class="attachment-medium" alt="redirect-150x150-700x30" width="700" height="30"></a></center>
<!---Content-->
</div>
```

I need to change _http://mysite.com/go/ to http://*mynewsite*.com/go/

Any help ? what code should be?, im searching on stackoverflow but none thread solves my problem.

Comment: when should the change be effected? on button click (or) page load (or) ??

Comment: and for one link or all the links or...?

Comment: for all links and on page load

Comment: If you can't access FTP, how is this going to help you?

Comment: Im use wordpress, I could put the code in html widget. my theme files can not be edited from the panel because they require write permissions, I need the ftp works in order to make my files to be editable

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am assuming you have some frontend (CMS?) access and no direct file access.

You can put it in the head section of every document.

```
function fixLinks(){
    var links =  document.getElementsByTagName('a');//Get all links
    for(i = 0 ; i<links.length ; i++){//Loop throught links
    var curLink = links[i].href // Cache
    links[i].href = curLink .replace('mysite','mynewsite');//Replace mysite with my newsite and return the fixed string
    }
  }
window.onload = fixLinks;
```

Comment: only works if I place it in the header?, I use wordpress, and I would like to place it in a widget.

Comment: thanks for your reply, it works like a charm, but, if i need to change all code from `<a href="http://misite.com/go/redirect.php?q=post title" target="_blank"><img src="http://mysite.com/img/redirect.png" class="attachment-medium" alt="redirect-150x150-700x30" width="700" height="30"></a>` to `<any code>` ? what will be the best code? thanks in advance

Comment: That really depends on what you need to do. You can build DOM elements with javascript and append them to code. That will be the best way https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/document.createElement?redirectlocale=en-US&redirectslug=DOM%2Fdocument.createElement